# SSIS doesn't save any changes

Tags: etl, savechanges, ssis-2017

I have an SSIS project on VS2017 and in it, I have a connections manager. I also have connection strings to files on the server. I am in the middle of the migration process, so I have to replace the paths to all files. But when I replaced the old path with the updated path, SSIS doesn't save anything and I can still see the relevant errors, even when I execute the package...

[image]

What can I do to make SSIS save the updated path?
I added here an image showing what string I replace and after saving - of course, nothing changes. I also tried to update the path using an XML file or another window but after executing the package or exiting - the old path kept.

Please help me.

Comment: Are you using any variables for the path definition ?

Comment: I think we use an expression.

Comment: Can you share the expression ?

Comment: @[User::FilePath] + @[User::NOD]  + @[User::FileType] + @[User::DateFile] + ".txt"

Comment: Can you show the input and the expected result?